# Can't access object property in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, object, laravel-5

I started learning Laravel since yesterday and face some difficulties to get property of an object.

Here is the class (created with `artisan`) :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Task extends Model
{
    public $description;
    public $completed;
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function isComplete()
    {
        return $this->completed;
    }
}
```

And here is the issue :

```
>>> $tasks = App\Task::all();
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#654
     all: [
       App\Task {#652
         id: "1",
         description: "Learn Laravel",
         completed: "0",
       },
     ],
   }
>>> $tasks[0]->id
=> 1
>>> $tasks[0]->description
=> null
```

Why can I access the `id` but can not access the `description` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make your model property as follow

```
protected $table = 'your table name';
protected $primaryKey = 'id';
protected $fillable = ['description','completed'];
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer. But in this case, how do I save the object ? Does `$task->save();` will work as expected ?

Comment: yes dear, it will work for you. what you have written code for save the task ?

Comment: Here is the save part : `$task = new Task; $task->description = request('taskName'); $task->completed = request('completed'); $task->save();`

Comment: `request('taskName')` return value or not ? If yes then will work for you

Comment: Ok, Thank you. I'll give this a try.

Comment: Validate yours because its the right way to do it. Thanks again !

Comment: The question was about declared property `$description` ("object property") of the class of the model `Task`, not about dynamic property `description` of the Laravel model from DB. 

By the way, if you have in your DB field `description` for your model `Task`, then this construction `protected $fillable` does not affect on `Task::all()` at all. When you will remove class field $description (unimportant public or protected), you will be able to get access to the field `description` of the each fetched task from your DB by `Task::all()`;

Answer (score 2):

Field `description` is empty because you have public field in your model with the same name:

```
public $description;
```

Just remove it and you will be able use value of the field `description` from the DB table of your model.

Comment: Thank you. I set them to `protected` instead.

Comment: This will work, but I suggest to use unique name for your class field.